# python heatmap with uneven box sizes

Tags: python, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap for stock returns like the one used in https://finviz.com/map.ashx, which looks like:

[image]

Does anyone know how to create something like this in python?  The closest I've found is "Heatmap with Unequal Block Sizes" for plotly, https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/.  I could probably make that work by subdividing everything into dozens of smaller heatmaps and then gluing them together in Dash, but is there a better way?  Does anyone know of a tool that makes this type of graph, or would I have to make it from scratch?

Comment: This is a [treemap chart](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/), not a heat map. :)

Comment: That would explain it!  Thank you, the plotly link solves it.

Answer (score 0):

This link has the examples:

https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/

And here is one working example:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```